# Remove a spirit qi symbol in semantic action

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

In other threads I've read how to add a symbol to the symbol table in a semantic action, but I don't know how to remove it.

The idea behind my question is, that I want to allow to rename keywords in the parsed text. So, several keywords with values are given, but the user can reassign them:

```
reassign(keyword)(mykeyword)
```

I have a rule with semantic action

```
using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
...
qi::symbols<char, TYPE> keywords;
...
key_replace = ( lit("reassign") >> lit("(") >> keywords >> lit(")") >> 
                                   lit("(") >> lexeme [ raw [ ( alpha >> *( alnum | '_' ) ) ] ] >> lit (")") ) 
              [ boost::phoenix::bind(keywords.remove, _1) ]; // TODO: replace not remove
```

The problem is, that I don't get a reference to the symbol itself, but to the stored value. So calling remove doesn't work.

How can I get a reference to the parsed symbol during parsing?

Is there a simpler way to exchange a symbol while preserving the value during parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naive 'phoenix' way would be to

```
 rule_assign = key >> value
        [ phx::bind(keywords.add, _1, _2) ];
 rule_remove = key
        [ phx::bind(keywords.remove, _1) ];

 // and voila: (BROKEN)
 rule_replace = key >> value
        [ phx::bind(keywords.remove, _1),
          phx::bind(keywords.add, _1, _2)
        ];
```

The latter doesn't work, I believe due to the fact that the first bind returns an object that overloads `operator,` itself, and it gets preferred over `phoenix`'s `operator,`.

I suggest you work around this by writing a little helper:

```
struct assign_symbol_f
{
    assign_symbol_f(Symbols& sym) : sym(sym) {}

    typedef bool result_type;

    template<typename Key, typename Value>
    bool operator()(Key const& key, Value const& value) const
    {
        bool replaced = (nullptr != sym.find(key));

        sym.remove(key); 
        sym.add(key, value);

        return replaced;
    }

private:
    Symbols& sym;
};
```

This transparently assigns or reassigns an item in a `symbols` tree. Use it as follows:

```
rule_replace_or_add = key >> value
        [ phx::bind(assign_symbol_f(keywords), qi::_1, qi::_2) ];
```

Now, you could split things and be more specific:

```
assign_symbol_f assign_sym(keywords);

rule_assign = key >> value
        [ qi::_pass = !phx::bind(assign_sym, _1, _2) ];

rule_replace = key >> value
        [ qi::_pass =  phx::bind(assign_sym, _1, _2) ];
```

### Bonus

As a bonus you can have a little bit of *syntactic sugar* by creating a lazy actor for your functor:

```
phx::function<assign_symbol_f> assign_sym;

// use it like
rule_assign = key >> value
        [ qi::_pass = assign_sym(_1, _2) ];

rule_replace = key >> value
        [ qi::_pass = assign_sym(_1, _2) ];
```

Look ma! No more `phx::bind`.

### Full demo

Complete with a rudimentary test suite :)

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <string>

namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

typedef qi::symbols<char, int> Symbols;

struct assign_symbol_f
{
    assign_symbol_f(Symbols& sym) : sym(sym) {}

    typedef bool result_type;

    template<typename Key, typename Value>
    bool operator()(Key const& key, Value const& value) const
    {
        bool replaced = (nullptr != sym.find(key));

        sym.remove(key); 
        sym.add(key, value);

        return replaced;
    }

private:
    Symbols& sym;
};

template <typename Iter> struct parser : qi::grammar<Iter, qi::space_type> 
{
    parser(Symbols &dict) 
        : parser::base_type(start), 
          assign_sym(dict)
    {
        using namespace qi;
        identifier = +graph;

        add_rule = lit("+") >> (identifier >> int_)
            [ assign_sym(_1, _2) ]
            ;

        del_rule = lit("-") >> identifier
            [ phx::bind(dict.remove, _1) ]
            ;

        start = (del_rule | add_rule) % ";";
    }

  private:
    phx::function<assign_symbol_f> assign_sym;

    qi::rule<Iter, qi::space_type> start, del_rule, add_rule;
    qi::rule<Iter, std::string()> identifier; // no skipper
};

bool execute(std::string const& test, Symbols& dict)
{
    auto f = test.begin(), l = test.end();

    parser<std::string::const_iterator> prsr(dict);
    return 
        qi::phrase_parse(f, l, prsr, qi::space)
        && (f == l);
}

int main() {
    Symbols dict;

    assert(execute("+foo 3; +bar 4; -foo", dict));

    assert(!dict.find("foo"));
    assert( dict.find("bar") && (4 == dict.at("bar")));
    assert(!dict.find("zap"));

    assert(execute("+zap -42; +bar 5; +foo 33", dict));

    assert( dict.find("zap") && (-42 == dict.at("zap")));
    assert( dict.find("bar") && (5   == dict.at("bar"))); // replaced
    assert( dict.find("foo") && (33  == dict.at("foo")));
}
```

Comment: I think we missunderstood. I wanted to change the name of an existing symbol while preserving its value. However, your answer showed me how I get access to the parts I need, so I could solve it. Thank you very much.